# Removing unnecessary inverted commas(') in Pandas DataFrame cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

What I actually mean to do is replace strings looking like this " '0.2' " with float value 0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want replace only columns filled by strings repr of numbers use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) per all columns of list:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(str(x).strip("'"), errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: @Sriman - Added removed traling `'` by `str.strip`, can you check it?

Comment: @ansev - Because OP need dynamic replace, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60813253/revisions)

Comment: Edit:   List of column names is not being accepted.Also, some of the values are already float. So, changed it to str(x)